# How can I check if `File::Path::remove_tree` failed?

Tags: perl, error-handling

I'm used to `... or die ".. failed... $!";.

I was surprised to find that in order to know if `File::Path::remove_tree` failed or not I must do something like this:

```
remove_tree( 'foo/bar', 'bar/rat', {error => \my $err} );
if (@$err) {
 die "error..."
}
```

Am I missing something? Is this really the way to go?

A lot of unneeded code for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remove_tree` returns the number of files successfully deleted, so it needs another method of reporting an error than a return value. Bear in mind that a number of files may have been deleted before an error is encountered, so you can't rely on the returned value being 0 as indicating an error.

Whether this is the way to go for reporting errors is a matter of taste. From the docs themselves:

> NOTE:
>   The following error handling mechanism is considered experimental and is subject to change > pending feedback from users.

Comment: in other words "If you have a better idea, I'm all ears!"

Answer (score 1):

I remove one path at a time then check if it is still there afterward:

```
 foreach my $path ( @paths ) {
      my $rc = remove_tree( $path, { ... } );
      die ... if -e $path;
      }
```

As [Dancrumb said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790259/how-can-i-check-if-filepathremove-tree-failed/3790322#3790322), you can't trust the return value.

Comment: +1 Yeah, I know the return value is irrelevant here. I just wondered if that's common to failure testing to be so "demanding".

Comment: When I'm dealing with the system and it matters, this is what I do. It's not that demanding.

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aPath#ERROR_HANDLING) say that it raises exceptions:

> If make_path or remove_tree encounter an error, a diagnostic message will be printed to STDERR via carp (for non-fatal errors), or via croak (for fatal errors).

That enabled us to use standard exception handling at least for the errors marked fatal.

```
use Try::Tiny;
try {
    … remove_tree …
} catch {
    warn "remove_tree failed: $_";
};
```

The warnings can be fatalised somehow, too, but I can't of anything decent right now except aliasing `File::Path::_carp` to `File::Path::_croak`.